# Submit app to app store with architecture armv7s and above only.

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, xcode6.1, ios8.1

We have developed an app which uses some c++ libraries compiled for armv7s(iPhone5 and iPhone5C) architecture and the app runs fine on arm64(iPhone5S)as well but while uploading the app to app store in validation process am getting error as : "this bundle is invalid. apps that include an armv7s architecture are required to include an armv7". Is there anyway where i can restrict our app to be installed on armv7s and above supported architecture devices only.

Comment: Can't you compile those c++ libraries for armv7 as well and compile your app also for the armv7 platform?

Comment: no, we are unable to compile those libraries for armv7.

Comment: You'd have to ask Apple to confirm, but given that they still sell armv7 devices (the iPhone 4S), it is likely that it is their intent to require all apps in the App Store to be compatible with all Apple-supported devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a way to resolve it by simply creating 3 different static libraries for armv7 , armv7s and arm64 and then created a fat static library using command `lipo -create mylibraryarmv7.a mylibraryarmv7s.a mylibraryarm64.a -output mylibrary.a`